# Finding leaf nodes in a Neo4J database

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

We have a project where we use Spring Data Neo4J.  One of the important entities is shown below:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Category {
    @GraphId
    Long id;

    String name;

    @RelatedTo(direction = Direction.INCOMING, type = "CHILD")
    Category parent;

    @RelatedTo(direction = Direction.OUTGOING, type = "CHILD")
    Set<Category> children;
}
```

We have a requirement to find out all the leaf categories (that is, categories without any children) starting from a specific category whose name is known.  For example, given the hierarchy shown below:

```
Electronics
    Camera
        Point and Shoot
        SLR
    Computing
        Desktop
        Laptop
        Tablet
        Netbook
Furniture
    Tables
        Office tables
        Home tables
    Chairs
        Lounge chairs
        Office chairs
```

a search for "Furniture" should return "Office tables", "Home tables", "Lounge chairs" and "Office chairs".  Similarly, a search for "Computing" should return "Desktop", "Laptop", "Tablet" and "Netbook".

Need help in creating a cypher query that can be placed on a Spring Data repository method to give me all the leaf nodes starting from the specified node.

**EDIT** The following query (with the associated Spring Data repository method) worked after help from Wes:

```
@Query(
"START  category=node:__types__(className='org.example.domain.Category') " +
"MATCH  category-[:CHILD*0..]->child " +
"WHERE  category.name={0} AND NOT(child-[:CHILD]->()) " +
"RETURN child")
List<Category> findLeaves(String name);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is the simplest way I've found with cypher: 
    http://console.neo4j.org/r/cgrndo

```
start n=node(*) // you can specify a single node here if you want
match n-[r*]->m
where not(m-->()) // this limits m to be only leaf nodes 
return distinct m; // this returns the distinct leaf nodes (not necessary if there are only simple paths)
```

Edit: (since people are recently upvoting this... here's an update using 3.x cypher)

```
match (n) 
where not (n)-->() 
return distinct n
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking to find all the **leaf nodes** in cypher 3.0 
http://console.neo4j.org/r/leaf-nodes

`match (n)-[r]-()
 with n, count(r) as c
 where c = 1 
 return n`

Comment: This only works if relationship direction isn't a factor in the graph's parent/child relationship (where both nodes in a 2-node subgraph would be considered leaf nodes). Otherwise this won't work, as the query will also match on the parent of a 2-node subgraph (as well as its child). By definition a leaf node is a node without any child nodes (but at least one parent node), and that is not what this query is checking. This query will also fail to identify leaf nodes in a non-tree graph, where there are multiple incoming relationships but no outgoing relationships.

Comment: Yes for an undirected graph